# Is there "danger" in removing Macintosh HD from my Time Machine as a back up? I want to use Seagate Backup Plus Drive

Tags: backup

I'm a novice (obviously!), and my Seagate will not back up my computer because it says there is nothing to back-u since my Macintosh HD is in my "Exclude these items from backups" under "Options".  I'm having a little anxiety if I take it off the list -- that I will lose all that is on it.  Call me crazy.  I just need some confirmation since I do not put it on this list so I assume it should be there.

Comment: If you post a screen shot of the image we might be clearer. I'll try to answer based on my understanding of the question.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's the Seagate app itself that changed the config, as 'Backup Plus' is a backup strategy in its own right [though not one I'm familiar with] Maybe it's trying to replace Time Machine, rather than work alongside it.

Answer (score 1):

None of the items in the "Exclude these items from backups" will be backed up. Usually only the backup volume (i.e. the Seagate Backup Plus Drive) itself is in the list.

So including *Macintosh HD* in the above list is counterproductive if you want to backup *Macintosh HD*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about Time Machine and losing data here are two safe ways to change things.

1. Only delete files when you enter the time machine interface - a small finder window, a blurred background and the list of time backup intervals on the right side of the screen running vertically from now (bottom) to the oldest backup (top). If you delete a file or a backup there, it prompts you for a password so you are sure to want it gone before it gets erased.
2. If you remove something from the Time Machine preference, that only removes an *exclusion* - so that means the next backup will copy more files to the external drive going forward. Basically the double negative means removing an exclusion includes more files. No actual data on the drive is deleted, no data on the backup destination is deleted - just the settings for the app change.